# Changing a UIButton to be turned off

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a simple button with two images for each `UIControlState`s. 
I want this button to behave as a control and as indicator so that I can press it down - "activate" and press again "deactivate", While some other functions can cause it to be turned off ("deactivate").
My question is how can I change it's state from selected to not-selected?
Changing the `selected` property would not do the trick :)

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the button so it can't be press able.

```
yourButton.enabled = NO;
```

and When you want it back to be press able, then you can enabled it

```
yourButton.enabled = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way would be consider button as switch and change it's state according switch on/off. For example use BOOL variable which upon button touch gets its value YES or NO while according to it button gets its image.

```
- (void) buttonTouched:(id)sender
{
    switchOn = !switchOn;
    UIImage *buttonImage = nil; 

    if (switchOn == YES) 
    { 
        buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"on.png"]; 
    }
    else
    {
        buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"off.png"]; 
    }
    [myButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [myButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
}
```

if you need to programmatically set button "disabled":

```
- (void) setButtonDisabled
{
    switchOn = YES; //calling buttonTouched: will turn it to NO
    [self buttonTouched:nil];
}
```